# Cocoa Pod Syntax error

Tags: xcode, workspace, cocoapods

Im running Maverick with Cocoa pods version 0.27.1.

I've created a pod file in textedit in plain format with following text.

```
workspace ‘DemoWorkspace'
platform :ios, 6.0


pod 'XMPPFramework' , '~> 3.6.1'
pod 'AFNetworking' , '~> 2.0.0'
pod 'FMDB', '~> 2.1'


end
```

and I get the following syntax error

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: .../Podfile:5: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting end-of-input
pod 'XMPPFramework' , '~> 3.6.1'
                  ^. Updating CocoaPods might fix the issue.
```

I dont understand whats going wrong in the above pod file.

Comment: Did you copy/paste this? Maybe it's irrelevant but the left quotation mark on `DemoWorkspace` is a 'curly' one...

Comment: Its something wrong with my TextEdit.

Comment: try `pod install --verbose` and see what the error is

Answer (score 32, accepted):

4 things actually:

Your format is incorrect. It should be:

```
pod 'XMPPFramework', '~> 3.6.1'
```

Remove the space between 'XMPPFramework' and ,

Secondly,
the first quote on the first line isn't a correct quote:

```
‘DemoWorkspace'
```

Thirdly,
you should define your platform with quotes around iOS version

```
platform :ios, '6.0'
```

Fourthly,

make sure you use a correct texteditor. As "Saqib Saud" found out, TextEdit sometimes messes with use of quotes <=> curly quotes.

I recommend [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) or Nano

Comment: this thing is really killing me. on maverick this ’ is default single quote is somewhat different. Im having issues because of single quote.

Comment: for the timebeing, not using TextEdit helps, instead use 'nano Podfile'

Comment: @SaqibSaud If you're in need of a great texteditor for mac, I use http://www.sublimetext.com/

Comment: Thanks Thomas I've been looking for something like this

Comment: @SaqibSaud I shall edit my answer so that users have to make sure they use a correct texteditor!

Comment: Simply use double quotes, and you don't have to use expensive text editors: pod "XMPPFramework", "~> 3.6.1"

Comment: I used to put >= instead of ~> and that was what causing the issue for me!

Answer (score 0):

I solved my by removing space between **:** **and** **ios**

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
```